# How do I find all subfolders of a folder?

Tags: haskell, io, monads

I’d like to enumerate all subfolders of a folder in Haskell. Getting all folder contents is easy, there’s a `getDirectoryContents` function. But how do I filter them? Since `getDirectoryContents` returns a `IO [FilePath]` and `filter` expects `[a]`, I can’t put those two directly together. (Obviously, I’m a fresh fish with monads and do-notation.)

```
getAllFolders :: FilePath -> IO [FilePath]
getAllFolder path = do
    allItems <- getDirectoryContents path
    -- now what? the predicate is doesDirectoryExist
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem is not that `getDirectoryContents` has the return type `IO [FilePath]`, you get a plain list of `FilePath`s by binding the result,

```
getAllFolders path = do
    contents <- getDirectoryContents path
    -- do something with contents now, it's a plain [FilePath]
```

the problem is that the predicate `doesDirectoryExist` has the type `FilePath -> IO Bool`. For such things, there is

```
ghci> :t Control.Monad.filterM
Control.Monad.filterM :: Monad m => (a -> m Bool) -> [a] -> m [a]
```

`filterM` defined in `Control.Monad`, so

```
getAllFolders path = do
    contents <- getDirectoryContents path
    filterM doesDirectoryExist contents
```

or, without binding the contents of the directory to a name,

```
getAllFolders path = getDirectoryContents path >>= filterM doesDirectoryExist
```

and point-free:

```
getAllFolders = getDirectoryContents >=> filterM doesDirectoryExist
```

Comment: Thank you! There’s an additional problem with relative/absolute filepaths, but I can figure that out.

Comment: That problem with relative paths is constantly tripping me up - to the point where I invented a library just to get around it! Also, `getDirectoryContents` always returns `.` and `..`, which is annoying.

Comment: `>=>` mmmm. We like `>=>`.

Answer (score 3):

Looks like `filterM` offered by `Control.Monad` is the answer:

```
getAllFolders :: FilePath -> IO [FilePath]
getAllFolders path = do
    allItems <- getDirectoryContents path
    justFolders <- filterM doesDirectoryExist allItems
    return justFolders
```

Comment: Correct. You can also combine the last two lines into just `filterM doesDirectoryExist allItems`, since `x <- foo; return x` is the same as just `foo`.